# YouTube API: How to specify an API callback after an uploaded video has finished encoding?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am uploading videos using the YouTube/Gdata API (in python).

After a video has been uploaded via the API, I receive the a response with data about the video (Youtube link, id, etc). However, the video is not publicly available while it is being encoded by YouTube (typically a few minutes).

**Can I specify a callback url that YouTube can post to after it finishes processing the video?**

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

You need to [poll using the video id to and check the 'state' of the video](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_yt%3astate) to detect when 'processing' is no longer present.

Answer (score 0):

With Youtube's V3 API, you need to do something similar, but slightly different.

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=processingDetails&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Further details here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list