# youtube api v3 does something when a user uploads a new video

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, youtube, youtube-api

How can I do that when an user uploads a new video, my javascript code in node.js execute something?
I readed the docs and I didn't fond anything.

Comment: can you please explain the problem in a bit more detail. Are you (for instance) trying to get events/callbacks from youTube to your code when a user does something via your code? eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588239/youtube-api-how-to-specify-an-api-callback-after-an-uploaded-video-has-finished

Comment: @Offbeatmammal I'm trying to when de user uploads a video with the normal youtube, the code executes something.

Comment: afaik there's no way to get a callback for an action that wasn't initiated through the API so you'd need to poll the account to see if/when a new video appears